# How do I properly use "time.h" to return a number greater than zero? c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to calculate the time a certain function takes to run

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include "time.h"

int myFunction(int n)
{    
    .............
}

int n;
time_t  start;

std::cout<<"What number would you like to enter ";
std::cout << std::endl;
std::cin>>n;
start = clock();
std::cout<<myFunction(m)<<std::endl;
std::cout << "Time it took: " << (clock() - start) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/ 1000 ) << std::endl;
std::cout << std::endl;
```

This works fine in x-code (getting numbers such 4.2, 2.6 ...), but doesn't  on a linux based server where I'm  always getting 0. Any ideas why that is and how to fix it?

Comment: Don't include both `<ctime>` and `time.h`.

Comment: @Barry thanks. Tried removing each one. Still doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Doesn't compile, doesn't run, or gives an unexpected result?

Comment: How long does `myFunction` actually take?

Comment: @MatsPetersson around 20 ms

Comment: On some machines, the time per tick is around 10-20ms, so it's plausible that on a different machine, it takes such a short time that it's "zero" - is that the result you are getting?

Comment: "zero", yes, that's what I'm getting @MatsPetersson

Comment: If the problem is that you're getting a result of zero, that information needs to be in the question itself.

Comment: @rose What do you mean by "works fine on my mac, but doesn't on a linux based server"? Please edit the question to clearly define the results you expect to see and the results you do see.

Comment: @RobK when I run on xcode, I get numbers such 4.1, 4.3, 2.6, but when I run it on a linux server, I get 0 all the time

Comment: @rose Please edit the question. You want to make it as easy as possible for people to help you, right? Put it in the question, not in comments that people have to wade through to find all the information.

Answer (score 0):

The "tick" of `clock` may be more than `1/CLOCKS_PER_SEC` seconds, for example it could be 10ms, 15.832761ms or 32 microseconds.

If the time consumed by your code is smaller than this "tick", then the time taken will appear to be zero.

There's no simple way to find out what that is, other than - you could call `clock` repeatedly until the return-value is not the same as last time, but that may not be entirely reliable, and if the clock-tick is VERY small, it may not be accurate in that direction, but if the time is quite long, you may be able to find out.

For measuring very short times (a few milliseconds), and assuming the function is entirely CPU/Memory-bound, and not spending time waiting for file I/O or sending receiving packets over a network, then `std::chrono` can be used to measure the time. For extremely short times, using the processor time-stamp-counter can also be a method, although that can be quite tricky to use because it varies in speed depending on load, and can have different values between different cores.

In my compiler project, I'm using this to measure the time of things:

This part goes into a header:

```
class TimeTrace
{
public:
    TimeTrace(const char *func) : impl(0)
    {
        if(timetrace)
        {
            createImpl(func);
        }
    }
    ~TimeTrace() { if(impl) destroyImpl(); }

private:
    void createImpl(const char *func);
    void destroyImpl();
    TimeTraceImpl *impl;
};
```

This goes into a source file.

```
class TimeTraceImpl
{
public:
    TimeTraceImpl(const char *func) : func(func)
    {
    start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    }

    ~TimeTraceImpl()
    {
    end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    uint64_t elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end-start).count();
    std::cerr << "Time for " << func << " "
          << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << elapsed / 1000.0 << " ms" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> start, end;
    const char* func;
};

void TimeTrace::createImpl(const char *func)
{
    impl = new TimeTraceImpl(func);
}

void TimeTrace::destroyImpl()
{
    delete impl;
}
```

The reason for the rather comple `pImpl` implementation is that I don't want to burden the code with extra work when the timing is turned off (`timetrace` is `false`).

Of course, the smallest actual tick of `std::chrono` also varies, but in most Linux implementations, it will be nanoseconds or some small multiple thereof, so (much) better precision than `clock`.

The drawback is that it measures the elapsed time, not the CPU-usage. This is fine for when the bottleneck is the CPU and memory, but not for things that depend on external hardware to perform something [unless you actually WANT that measurement].